# How can I split a string into a constant number of characters, moving 1 character at a time?

Tags: split

I would really appreciate your help.

I want to split a fasta file into strings of 7 characters separated by newlines and save the output in a new file.

input file:

```
$ cat file.fasta  

name_of_the_protein  
MRPPQCLLHTPSLASPLLLLLLWLLGGGVGAEGREDAELLVTVRGGRLRGIRLKTPGGPVSAFLGIPFAE  
PPMGPRRFLPPEPKQPWSGVVDATTFQSVCYQYVDTLYPGFEGTEMWNPNRELSEDCLYLNVWTPYPRPT
```

expected output:

```
$ cat new_file.txt  

MRPPQCL  
RPPQCLL  
PPQCLLH  
PQCLLHT  
QCLLHTP  
CLLHTPS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you clarified the original request, you may run `awk` from the linux or cygwin command line to get what you like:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN { targetLength=7 } (NR>1) { for(i=1; i < length($0)-targetLength+2; i++) { print(substr($0,i,targetLength)) }     
}' file.fasta
```

Alternatively you put the following content into a separate file (`sequencer.awk`):

```
BEGIN { targetLength=7 }
(NR>1) {
   for(i=1; i < length($0)-targetLength+2; i++) {
     print(substr($0,i,targetLength))
   }
}
```

and run it with `awk -f sequencer.awk file.fasta`.

This assumes you only have two lines in your file, one with the name, one with the sequence (beware that some text viewers introduce linewrapping). If you have more than two lines, the results for each line would concatenate on the output.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much, both options work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify which language you want to use, I quickly did it javascript. Might not be too elegant, but verbose:

```js
const myString = 'ABCDEFGHIJK' // original string

const targetLength = 7 // length of extracted portion

const extractions = [] // an array to hold all extracted parts

for(let i = 0; i < myString.length - targetLength + 1; i++) {
  extractions.push(myString.substring(i, targetLength + i))
}

console.log(extractions.join("\n"))
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the language. I use cygwin, could you do it with akw please?

Comment: Cygwin is no language, but rather a Linux-like environment for Windows, so I suppose you want to write it like a BASH script (a script that runs and gets interpreted from your console) or indeed as an AWK script?

Comment: Yes, I want it as a bash script because I would like to apply it to different nucleotide sequence files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where do you get your input data from? If its files, then what structure do they have. Is it an input argument to your script? Or prompted user input at runtime? Can you edit your original question to make that more clear?

Comment: It is a file which contains the name of the protein in the first line and the following lines contain the amino acid sequence. I have already modified the original question, I hope it is more clear.